# PHP gethostbyaddr: does not return computer name from the live server?

Tags: php, ip, php-5.4, gethostbyaddr

I want to get the computer name that access a page. So this question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248204/how-to-get-the-computer-name-from-ip-address).

I tested on my localhast,

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname;
```

I get my computer name, such as,

```
lau-pc
```

But when I run this code on my live server, I don't get my computer name, I get ip address instead,

```
123.136.xxx.xx
```

how come? So I can't get the computer name from the live server then?

Comment: According to the documentation gethostbyaddr returns the original ip, if the name resolution failed. You can test your servers settings if you can logon via ssh with a "host 123.136.xxx.xxx" command. Probably there will be some kind of misconfiguration.


Otherwise REMOTE_ADDR is not 100% safe. Probably you should not build important logic on it. (REMOTE_ADDR will show the proxies ip address if the client is behind a proxy.)

And dns resolution can be painfully slow... Which can be unacceptable in online environmets.